# Row_Number() would return different return values as TSQL and User Defined function

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, window-functions, sql-function

I have a table Products with 57 rows in it. I have the below user defined function

```
    Create alter FUNCTION [dbo]. [ufn_GenerateNewProductId]()
    RETURNS nvarchar (MAX)
    as
    begin
    declare @NewproductId nvarchar(MAX), @rowNum int
    select @rowNum=ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ProductId) from Products;
    set @rowNum=@rowNum+1+100;
    set @NewproductId='P' + cast(@rowNum as nvarchar(MAX));
    return @NewproductId;
    end
```

When I call the user defined function as below, it has value 'P158' in @product:

```
declare @product nvarchar(max);

select @product= dbo.ufn_GenerateNewProductId();

print @product;
```

When I call it as below, it would return the value 'P102'.

```
select dbo.ufn_GenerateNewProductId();
```

Please help me understand why is the difference in behaviour of Row_Number() in both the cases.

Comment: Your user defined function just doesn't make sense.  Presumably, the query returns multiple rows.  An arbitrary value is then assigned to the variable.

Comment: `select @rowNum=ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ProductId) from Products;` doesn't really make much sense. That `SELECT` us going to return a dataset, and you're assigning to a scalar variable. That should be `SET @rowNum = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM from Products);`

Comment: I also suspect there's some scalar inlining "features" going on here, but that isn't the function's fault here, and is the way the function has been written.

Comment: returns nvarchar(max)? try again.

Comment: `Create alter function` is also not valid syntax.

Comment: Also, looking at the function's name `ufn_GenerateNewProductId` suggests you are doing this to create a new id for the table. This is not going to work properly as soon as you have 2 or more simultaneous transactions. SQL Server has a `IDENTITY` property, and `SEQUENCE` objects for a reason.

Comment: This behavior is a side effect of scalar inlining for 2019. `select [dbo]. [ufn_GenerateNewProductId]()  OPTION (USE HINT('DISABLE_TSQL_SCALAR_UDF_INLINING'));` It does not occur on earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

The query returns multiple rows, so it is undefined which value is actually assined to the scalar variable.

It looks like you actually want `count(*)`:

```
create or alter function [dbo].[ufn_generatenewproductid]()
returns nvarchar (max)
as
begin
    declare @newproductid nvarchar(max), @cnt int;
    select @cnt = count(*) + 101 from products;
    set @newproductid='P' + cast(@cnt as nvarchar(max));
    return @newproductid;
end
```

Note that you can skip one of the variable and compute directly the new product id:

```
create or alter function [dbo].[ufn_generatenewproductid]()
returns nvarchar (max)
as
begin
    declare @newproductid nvarchar(max);
    select @newproductid = concat('P', count(*) + 101) from products;
    return @newproductid;
end
```

Comment: I have found this behaviour by  accident, I just wanted to understand the difference in behaviour. That question is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want to generate a new product id, where the id value is one larger than the current number of products.

If so, you want logic like this:

```
Create alter FUNCTION dbo.ufn_GenerateNewProductId()
RETURNS nvarchar (MAX)
as begin
    declare @NewproductId nvarchar(MAX), @rowNum int

    select @NewproductId = concat('P', COUNT(*) + 1)
    from Products;
    return @NewproductId;
end;
```

In case something gets deleted, you might want to use the current value and add 1:

```
Create alter FUNCTION dbo.ufn_GenerateNewProductId()
RETURNS nvarchar (MAX)
as begin
    declare @NewproductId nvarchar(MAX), @rowNum int

    select @NewproductId = concat('P', convert(int, max(stuff(productid, 1, 1, ''))) + 1)
    from Products;
    return @NewproductId;
end;
```

I strongly discourage you from doing either of these -- the code has concurrency issues and is much slower than alternatives.  Just use an `identity` column to define the id.